# What book has several humanoids with animal features in a story told from their perspectives?

Tags: story-identification

I don't know if I'm remembering it correctly, but I read a book that had 15–20 different characters in it, and told the story from their perspectives. I think they might have made a movie out of it too.

I wanna say they were human-looking, but with slight animal features; like a nose that looks like a bird beak, for example.

I remember one scene towards the end where they all meet up on a train one way or another to go towards the book's finale. I remember a few of them using magic to teleport into the train, and another somehow went down on a mine cart or something to get there.

What book is this?

Comment: Do you remember when you read it, or when it might have been published?

Comment: just that it was I was younger . I'm 32 now, so maybe in my youth sometime . :(

Comment: Take a look at [this list](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) for possible details you can include in your question

Comment: Not a great title.  Without the information about the bird breaks and the train this could be anything from The Canterbury Tales to Dracula.

Comment: Could it be *Fables* or *Fablehaven*? I'm not yet familiar with them, but they sound distantly related to what you're describing.

Comment: @Drax100: “just that it was I was younger” Helpful. Are you *sure* you didn’t read it when you were older than you are now?

Answer (score 3):

This reminds me of the 1998 fantasy novel [The Innkeeper's Song](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0285634291) by Peter Beagle. In particular the part about the rotating Points of view throughout the storyline and the magical aspects. I don't think it was 15-20 different views. But, it did give the impression of many more people than were actually involved because of the switching around. As it was published about 18-19 years ago and given you are 32 (you mentioned reading it sometime in your youth) that would seem about the right timing.

Peter Beagle is known as being something of a young adult author (e.g. the Last Unicorn) so that would also seem to make it a good chance it could have been something you might have read. Finally, you mention animal shapes/noses. One of the views is the nun's companion (a fox) who, as you might expect, has a sharp nose.

Below is a brief excerpt. Additional covers/descriptions can be found [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0451454146):

> Searching for his lover in a shadowy, magic world, young Tikat meets three mysterious cloaked women, whose quest involves saving their mentor, a once-powerful wizard, from losing his magic to a treacherous enemy.

The one thing that I am not immediately remembering is the train scene. But, it has been a few years since I read it.